# Angular 5 {{}} calculation in html

Tags: angular, datatable, calculation

I'm trying to add margins to my datatable which would be revenue **minus** cost.

Right now my code looks like this on the html.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="margin">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Margin</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.revenue - project.cost}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

The app shows the right number, but I'm not able to sort the column by ascending or descending order. I'm guessing because I'm calculating it in the HTML. How can I work around this?

Comment: Are you using PrimeNG data table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate this in your `controller`.

The approach used by you is not the recommended way because the above calculation will happen with every change detection. But its possible that this value might only change once or on a particular action. So handling this in controller will avoid this and increase performance.